# SDK error Android Studio

Tags: android

Welcome , I admit  that I'm new in Android Studio , somethimes and only somethimes during the esecution of the program it appears an error called SDK ERROR. what is it and how to fix it ? and why it appears in different times ? THANKS

Comment: Can you be more specific. Share the error output. Have you been able to run your code yet? Did you set the Android SDK in your IDE.

Comment: THANKS ! i only need to set the Android SDK in my IDE.